# How do I stop a sharkbite brand fitting from spinning?

Tags: plumbing, pushfit

I recently replaced a number of shutoffs with SharkBite brand push on fittings. These seem to work well and hold water. More expensive, but cheaper than relearning to solder for a small job.

The only issue I have is that they spin around. I can find many references to the fact that they spin but I cannot find any remarks as to how to stop them from spinning.

The rotation is a problem with the angle-stops. When the valve knob is turned to open or close the flow the fitting spins so you have to use two hands to turn the valve.

How can I stop a a sharkbite fitting from spinning?

Comment: Are you sure the pipe is fully seated?  Is this on copper pipe or PEX?

Comment: @Tester101 - Yes the fitting is seated. I marked the depth before pushing it on. This is to copper.

Answer (score 3):

Epoxy.

Really. Epoxy the fitting right to the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You know that there are compression shut-offs that don't spin?  They are sold usually by toilet repair and normal shutoffs at big box store.  Just get the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Silicone tape along the base of the SharkBite valve should keep it from rotating on the pipe. Make sure the silicone tape overlaps itself (that's how it sticks). Make sure you allow enough time for the tape to fuse to itself as well.

[Example silicone tape](http://www.xtremetape.com)